# Problema al abrir el projecto php me sale error

Tags: php7, pdo

Tengo un proyecto conectado por ***pdo*** y cuando lo abro en ***localhost*** me lanza este error:

> Warning: include(/core/models/conexion.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDConBuscador-master\core\controllers\homeUserController.php
> on line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/core/models/conexion.php' for
> inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDConBuscador-master\core\controllers\homeUserController.php
> on line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDConBuscador-master\core\controllers\homeUserController.php
> on line 5
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
> null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDConBuscador-master\core\controllers\homeUserController.php:5
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDConBuscador-master\index.php(7):
> require() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUDConBuscador-master\core\controllers\homeUserController.php
> on line 5 este es el archivo que menciona el error

Este es el archivo que menciona el error:

[image: este es el archivo que menciona el error]

Y esta es mi conexión:

```
<?php
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=4473; dbname=convenios','root','');
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conexion->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR EN LA CONEXION ".$e->GetMessage();
        echo "<br>LINEA DEL ERROR ".$e->GetLine();
    }
?>
```

Comment: EN VEZ DE :include('/core/models/conexion.php');       PRUEBA: include('../models/conexion.php');

Comment: gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como va.

Siempre que la fuente de errores con can't find such file o directory son problemas de importación.

include 'directorio/archivo.php';  (Notese que no le puse la barra adelante).

Un buen helper que te puede ayudar a apuntar correctamente tus includes es

```php
echo __DIR__; //->C:\xampp\htdocs\test  

include (__DIR__ . '/test.php');
```

**DIR**  va a devolver el directorio actual donde se encuentra el archivo de donde es llamado. Y desde ahí moverte para donde necesites.

```html
<?php

//Codigo del test.php

include('controller/controller.php');

echo $testController;


?>
```

[image: Imagen de estructura de carpetas semejante a la de la pregunta]

Espero haber ayudado!